# Cast error when drawing Subgraphs in MSAGL

Tags: c#, casting, subgraph, msagl

I have a root `Subgraph` object with four child `Subgraphs` each containing a few `Nodes`. I have added all the `Subgraphs` and `Nodes` to the `Graph` and set the `RootSubgraph` on the `Graph`. However, when trying to draw the `Graph` I get a cast error from within the library (`Microsoft.Msagl.GraphViewerGdi.Draw.cs`, line 1044) where the `GeometryNode` of a `Subgraph` is cast to a `Cluster`. The `GeometryNode` is set to a `Cluster` in `GeometryGraphCreator.ProcessSubgraphs` and the error message gives me no information about why the cast fails. How can I fix this?

For now I've simply set the `Label` to null to avoid the drawing code but I would like to use a label eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my initialisation of the `Subgraph`:

```
var subgraph = new Subgraph(id)
{
    Attr =
    {
        Id = id,
        FillColor = fillColor,
    },
    Label =
    {
       FontSize = 10,
       Text = id
    }
};
```

Assigning the `Label` property this way skipped some extra set up code needed to correctly link the `Label` with the `Subgraph`. Leaving it out altogether lets the constructor handle the `Label` itself.